# jQuery display server realtime response text while waiting ajax to finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to create a function to display server response while waiting the ajax to finish, the case is like this:

1. I checked several checkboxes, let's say it 10 checkboxes
2. Submit button is clicked and ajax is triggered
3. In the server side, there's a looping to execute every values from checkboxes, and this could take a long time per loop (now there will be 10 loop iterations)
4. Now while waiting the ajax to finish, I want to get the response from server (by the loop number), like `Getting data 1 of 10, (total) details obtained...`
5. After the ajax done, a response from server will be 'Operation succeeded, redirecting to result page'

---

Currently only other than number 4 working, and my current approach is:

1. I created 2 functions in CI, function A to loop and do the operation, function B to display the message set inside function A
2. I created 2 ajax functions, ajax X and ajax Y. X is used to get json response from B, while Y is used to submit and send the form to A.
3. I call ajax X first with setInterval 1 second, this ***works*** only once because it gets overridden by the ajax Y as soon as I start it. And when I tried to open function B in new tab (while ajax is still running), it just loading and only show the message after function A/ajax finished. Fortunately in Chrome I got this message while trying to open function B: `Waiting for active connection`

---

So how do I achieve this? Because my client is not an IT based and I want to show some progress text so that he knows how much data are being processed.

By the way currently I use only loading GIF and hide it while the ajax is done.

Any help or clues will be very appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making two functions is a bad idea because A() and B() even running parallel on same server cannot share their variables as such.You can archive that result with just one function and some clever use of buffering.I added `sleep` to match code that consumes some time.

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0); 
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();
session_write_close(); // prevents session lockdowns
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    sleep(1);   //Hard work!! zZZ
    $p = $i+1;
    echo  $p . ' of 10 complete ';  //get sent immediately
}

sleep(1);
echo '10 of 10 complete';
```

Note `ob_implicit_flush(true);` [implicit flush](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-implicit-flush.php) means as soon as you echo something it gets sent to browser immediately **without breaking your connection** so you will get 1,2,3... on each loop iteration all one by one from the same HTTP connection

Next comes javascript only point here you need to note is `onreadystatechange` gets called on not just state changes but om every response arrived from the server

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
var prevResponse = '';                   
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4){
        //stuff you want to do when ajax completes   
        alert('Done!')
    }
    else if (this.readyState > 2){
        var newResponse = this.responseText.substring(prevResponse.length);      
        document.getElementById("status").innerText = newResponse;
        prevResponse = this.responseText;
    }                     
};
xhr.open("GET", "ajax.php", true);
xhr.send();
```

Also one more point the **`responseText` property is buffering in nature** ie. if you send 'A' from your server `xhr.responseText` would give 'A' but now if you send 'B' `xhr.responseText` wouldn't be 'B' but instead 'AB' that's why I've used `prevResponse` to hold last response so that I can subtract this from current `responseText` to get only what server sent me this time.You can even go further and make it into a progress bar , just make the server send percentages in a JSON , decode that on client apply `value` to progress bar and with some cool CSS effects there you have it.

For $.ajax try this

```
$.ajax({
  url:'ajax.php',
  xhr: function(){ 
        var prevResponse = '';   
        var req = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4){
              //stuff you want to do when ajax completes   
            }
            else if (this.readyState > 2){
              var newResponse = this.responseText.substring(prevResponse.length);      
              document.getElementById("status").innerText = newResponse;
              prevResponse = this.responseText;
            }
        }             
        return req;
  }
  //other options
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is working, but when I tried to use $.ajax and override its xhr object with beforeSend and xhr parameter, it doesn't work. I'm using your answer rather then $.ajax to have this working :D

Comment: You're welcome.For jquery try the code I added it should work

Comment: @Novice Thank You very much. It works for me. Thank you

Comment: @Sourov Roy Chowdhury  Glad it helped you :)